# setting linux file permission inheritance using acls

Tags: linux, acl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to figure out linux file permission inheritance. As `root`, I've created a user `dadams`.

```
adduser dadams
```

Changed its primary group

```
usermod -g www-data dadams
```

Created a directory

```
mkdir /var/blah
```

Changed its group to `www-data` and added read, write, and execute permissions

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/blah
chmod -R g+rwx /var/blah
```

Set new content group inheritance

```
chmod g+s /var/blah
```

Changed the group permissions again using acls

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /var/blah
```

I then changed to my new user, `dadams` and created a file

```
su dadams
touch /var/blah/test.txt
```

but the permissions of the new file aren't what i expect. I expect the group to have all permissions but i get the following.

```
dadams@mybox:/var/blah$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwsr-x+  2 root   www-data 4096 Aug 14 16:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 root   root     4096 Aug 14 16:29 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 dadams www-data    0 Aug 14 16:30 test.txt
```

I clearly don't understand linux file permissions. What am i missing?

Comment: the umask for my `dadams` user is `0022` or `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`. That still doesn't line up with the permissions of the `test.txt` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if umask/acl says that a file should have `+x`, it doesn't actually happen unless the application says the file should be executable (through flags in the `open(2)` syscall).

This is because it's not useful to give people +x on files by default -- mp3 and png files are not executable, and having the executable flag set just confuses users and tools.

If you instead mkdir a directory or compile an executable with gcc, the group will get `+x` because on directories and executables this makes sense.

PS: consider using `g:www-data:rwx` if you want the `www-data` group to have permissions regardless of which group owns the file.

Comment: definitely good to know about +x. That would've driven me crazy. Another good tip with `g:www-data:rwx`. I think i understand a bit better. thanks!